# Can I change the class of an element that Ruby's Pluck returns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am familiarizing myself with the data in a database I inherited. And the `credit_amount` field is a `decimal` which when `pretty printed` returns something that looks like this:

```
<BigDecimal:6d28088,'0.0',9(18)>
```

I want to be able to read it, after I get the info using `pluck` and then `group_by` like this:

```
emails = Customer.pluck(:shop_id, :customer_id, :email, :credit_amount )
gemails = emails.group_by{ |shop_id, customer_id, email, credit_amount| customer_id }
pp gemails
```

Currently when this prints it looks like this:

```
 "21274984473"=>
  [[105,
    "21274984473",
    "XXXXCCCCC@gmail.com",
    Mon, 28 Aug 2017 16:39:28 UTC +00:00,
    #<BigDecimal:6d28088,'0.0',9(18)>],
   [105,
    "21274984473",
    "XXXXCCCCC@gmail.com",
    Wed, 02 Aug 2017 20:09:37 UTC +00:00,
    #<BigDecimal:a0e1690,'0.0',9(18)>]],
```

Just trying to read that `BigDecimal` number.. using `to_f` has worked in the past, just not sure where to put that here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
emails.each { |e| e[-1] = e[-1].to_f }
```